# Can't find Custom Location in iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, react-native, location, ios-simulator

I have an app, where I have different fields based on the device location.

Until now, I've always changed the location via **`Debug -> Location -> Custom Location`**
However, it seems Appled has update XCode Simulators and now you can no longer access custom location from the `Debug` options.

### Before:

[image]

### After:

[image]

**Any idea where I can access the Custom Location from now on?**

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it *(guess I'm blind)*!

**`Features -> Location -> Custom Location`** is the new way to set Custom Location.

[image]